# how to set text new line in Toast at center android

Tags: center, duration, android-toast

My Toast have 3 lines, I want line 2 and 3 show center of this toast and set duration to 10 seconds.

How can do it?

Like this picture:

[image]

Comment: <string name="my_tring_test">aaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\ncccccccccccccccc</string>


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_test), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 12):

\n inside the string works!!!

```
Toast.makeText(this, "line1\nLine2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: It works to add a new line but it does not center the text as OP asked.

Answer (score 5):

You can customize Toast class. Here is example:

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

        View customToastroot =inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_TOAST_LAYOUT, null);

        Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);

        customtoast.setView(customToastroot);
        customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);
        customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        customtoast.show();
```

For more details tutorials visit [here](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-toast-creating-a-android-custom-toast-example/) and [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-toast-example)

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(this,"YOUR MESSAGE",
                      +"\n"+
                     "Your other message",

Toast.Lenght_long).show();
```

Each time you add a line with

+"\n"+